# HTML canvas arc() Method in javascript only shows a small segment of the circle

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

```
//This function draws all the circles 
function drawCircle(x,y,r,col){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle=col;
  ctx.arc(x,y,r,Math.PI*2,true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

//this function I'm using to animate the circle
function animate(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  drawBlock();
  blockY+=dy;
  drawBall();
  ballY+=bdy;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

//this part calls the drawCircle() function
function drawBall(){
  drawCircle(ballX,ballY,ballr,"#ff7744");
}
```

I am trying to use this code to animate a circle on screen moving from the top down but all it shows is a segment of the circle from the circumference and then a small part of the circle shows up.

Comment: You're not calling `drawCircle`

Comment: i've added the part where i call the drawCircle function

Comment: You are missing one argument in `arc(cx, cy, r, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise)` here you are setting endAngle to `true`, it probably gets converted to `1`, so you'll draw only from 2π to 1 Ps: `closePath` is useless here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

drawCircle(50,50,50,'green');

function drawCircle(x,y,r,col){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle=col;
  ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

```css
canvas {
 border:2px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='c' width='400' height='400'></canvas>
```

`ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,true);`

[arc method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) takes 6 parameters,

1>x cordinate arc center,

2> y cordinate arc center,

3> radius length ,

4> start angle in radian ,

5>end angle in radian,

6> to draw in clockwise or anticlockwise.value boolean . Default clockwise, if true then it will draw anticlockwise.

In your case `ctx.arc(x,y,r,Math.PI*2,true)`, first 4 parameter are correct and true value convert to 1. and it takes 1 radian as endAngle. and it draws clockwise from 2 PI to 1 radian clcokwise. So you able to get a segment of arc only.